# Bot unable to use multiple tokens in text file

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a command for a bot which will log accounts online and cause them to randomly change from online to offline, here is my current code

```
@bot.command() 
async def onoff(ctx): # b'\xfc' 
    await ctx.message.delete()
    for _i in range(1000):    
        with open("tokens.txt", "r") as f:
            tokens = f.read().splitlines()
            for _token in tokens:
                headers = {
                    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': _token,
                }
                request = requests.Session()
        
                modes = cycle(["light", "dark"])
                statuses = cycle(["online", "invisible"])
                while True:
                        setting = {
                            'theme': next(modes),
                            'status': next(statuses)
                        }
                        while True:
                            try:
                                request.patch("https://canary.discordapp.com/api/v6/users/@me/settings",headers=headers, json=setting, timeout=10)
                                time.sleep(randint(1,2))
                            except Exception as e:
                                print(f"{Fore.RED}[ERROR]: {Fore.YELLOW}{e}"+Fore.RESET)
                            else:
                                break
```

My tokens are in tokens.txt separated by an enter key on the ends to separate them into lines. I have 2 tokens currently, but it only functions with the first token given. Any help would be happily accepted.

Comment: How could it?  The outer `while` loop never ends.

Comment: @TimRoberts I feel stupid for having missed that... oml thank you.

Comment: Pretty much your whole code is blocking, it's a really bad idea to use that approach

Comment: Oh wow, how I miss code waterfalls. My suggestion is to restyle your code entirely in a less nested fashion, maybe add some breaks and get back to original indentations, otherwise you'll slowly lose control over loops, conditionals, etc...and you'll make anyone dealing with your code tear their hair out :)